# Google Search Console crawled my shopify site but not appearing in google search with site: prefix

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, shopify

About 1 month ago i submitted my Shopify site to Google Search console, i set the sitemap.xml path which points to the Products, Blogs and Collection. I used the site: prefix on google as follows: site:nodosperu.com but i see none of my product pages listed there. So i reviewed the configurations again and for some reason it wasn't listing the products, so i manually added the products sitemap along with the pages sitemap since it didn't recognize it either.

[image]

Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue, i checked the robots.txt file and it is not excluding any of the files.

Is there any other setting that i have to change? Currently on Google search i can only see about 4 urls listed.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Google was either caching the results for you or the indexing wasn't finished yet as I am able to see your different collections on google:
[image: Google Results]

Comment: Correct, so yesterday after posting I added another attribute for my site, in this case I have set up a domain and site account. I used the URL inspection to manually add one of my products, which is the one listed. I have about 15+ products on my sitemap, but only see one. Could product stock options have something to do with this? I don’t think google validates if the product is in stock or not

Comment: I see 74 results in the site: search myself and it included 39 URLs with product in them

Answer (score 1):

I see much more results:

[image]

Thats because urls are indexed, which shouldn't be indexed. Your collections seem to be redundant - your products seem to appear in multiple collections. I would deindex collections at all.

Second thing: i would strongly avoid such construction as you build with sitemaps. Your site is too small - it doesn't need index sitemap and different sitemaps for every purpose. Think what feels Google finding a sitemap index with a sitemap, containing two urls, as your `sitemap_blogs_1.xml`. Google means - "is it a joke?", or "does this guy understand the sense of sitemap index?", or even "this guy doesn't mind my ressources and wastes my computing power".

In short: put all urls into the same sitemap and make a sitemap index after something of your blog or product urls reach an amount of 50.000.